# Simple question on the phrasing on a PBS Infinite Series video

Tags: quantum-computing

What does she mean by finding the 6 qubit quantum state $|010001\rangle$ from a sphere of dimension $2^6$.

Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrbJYsep45E 
at time 8:47.

Comment: You will probably have to ask the author of the video what she meant.

Answer (score 1):

The state of an $n$-qubit system is a superposition of the $2^n$ pure states
$$
\sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} \alpha_x \left| x \right\rangle,
$$
where the $\alpha_x$ are complex numbers satisfying $\sum_x |\alpha_x|^2 = 1$. The $2^n$-dimensional (complex) *sphere* is just
$$
\{ (\alpha_{0\dots0},\ldots,\alpha_{1\dots1}) \in \mathbb{C}^{2^n} : \sum_x |\alpha_x|^2 = 1 \}.
$$
I'm not sure what "finding" $\left|010001\right\rangle$ on the sphere means, though.

Comment: I'm just confused with the phrasing on the video. I understand this part, just not what it means to do a 6 qubit quantum computation.